# Calling a stored proc from Entity framework n times

Tags: performance, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I've got a stored proc on a database which I need to call n number of times from within Entity Framework.

```
    public Points GetResults(Share share, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            int? stockId = GetID(share, endDate);
            var data = ctx.GetData(stockId, 123, startDate, endDate, -23, 14, 3);
            var selectedPoints = data.Where(a => a.Date.HasValue && a.Value.HasValue).ToDictionary(a => a.Date.Value, a => a.Value.Value);
            return new Points(selectedPoints);
        }
    }
```

I have to call this for n number of shares (500 shares, 500 calls). I'm finding it to be a bit of a performance bottleneck for me at the moment. There is a lot of logic in the stored proc which I can't move out of the proc. Does anyone have any tips to speed this up? Or am I just buggered because I need to call this procedure n number of times?

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stored procedure only takes one StockId and you need the result for many then you have no choice but to call it 500 times, this is always going to be slow.

Really you'd need to look at modifying the SP, I'd suggest looking at table-valued parameters depending on the database engine in use.

Comment: I think that this is pretty much what I'm going to have to do. I can't edit the proc, but I can write my own sql. Seriously, you should see the sql, it's like >1000 lines long of dynamic horribleness.

Comment: LOL - I've so been there!  You could look at writing a new stored procedure that takes the set of IDs.  Within it you can then call the existing SP iteratively using a cursor, to call the existing SP use INSERT EXEC sp where you insert to a temp table.  Then SELECT the contents of the table at the end.  This should be much quicker as you don't have the network latency of the calls to contend with.